# How to blur entire body element when focus is lost?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to blur website when webpage loses focus. I tried using OnBlur and Focusin/out

I tried using OnBlur with the body tag, the html tag. I tried even listeners, a bunch of different JS, and other stuff.

I’m trying to make it so my website fades into a gaussian-like blur with some text that says something like “come baaaackkk :(“ or something stupid like that

Comment: I haven't downvoted - at least not so far - but I'd suggest it's because you've posted no code at all to illustrate either the problem you're facing, or any attempts at your solutions; you said you've tried using various techniques but haven't shown those attempts, or explained where/how they failed, or given us any insight into what errors have been reported (if any). So the down-vote is likely to be for the reason outlined in the tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event for this. Try the code below:

```js
const pageTitle = document.title;

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    const blurredDiv = document.createElement("div");
    blurredDiv.id = "blur";
    blurredDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Come Back :(</h1>";
    document.body.appendChild(blurredDiv);
    document.title = "Come Back :(";
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const blurredDiv = document.getElementById("blur");
      blurredDiv.parentNode.removeChild(blurredDiv);
      document.title = pageTitle;
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

The `document.hidden` checks if the tab is open, but not visible.
You don't need the `setTimemout` function, but I added it there so you can see it in action, and the overlay doesn't get removed instantly.

and the corresponding css:

```css
#blur {
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* For the h1 inside this div */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

If you want to see this in working take a better look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/zoclhas/pen/zYmMzQx)

Comment: `visibilitychange` fires once the tab/window loses focus, which means any message displayed to the user won't be seen (because that tab/window no longer has focus and isn't visible, unless the user is switching windows and keeps the browser visible).

Comment: But something like changing the document title would sort of display a message right?

Comment: Sure, but any graphical changes on the page - the blurring, and message that OP asks for - would not be visible (unless the message was in the title as you say).

Comment: Added code for changing the page title.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution that uses CSS only.
Feel free to modify it to your needs

```css
blurred {
  filter: blur(2px);
}

html:hover blurred {
  filter: blur(0)
}

html:hover unblurred {
  opacity: 0;
}

unblurred {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <blurred>
    This will get blurred
  </blurred>
  <unblurred>
    This will appear not blurred
  </unblurred>
</body>
```

Comment: How does this work?? Is there literally just a DOM that blurs??? I’m on mobile so I can’t technically hover over anything.

Comment: Yes, the tag blurred will get blurred when the mouse moves away. And the tag unblurred will become visible